# Snapping tools missing inside of UV Editor

Tags: uv, interface, snapping

Inside of my UV editor, I am missing the Snapping tool bar. I've going through Preferences, View menus and more to try and restore this with no luck. Without this option, I cannot snap and of my UV. I am using Blender 2.9.
[image: Missing Menu]

Comment: It looks as if it's off the right hand side of the screen because you can just see the pivot point dropdown right at the edge of the screen. Try holding the MMB down with the cursor over that row and dragging it to the left.

Comment: Are you opening a file that was created in Blender 3.x?

Comment: It appears as though it was opened in a later version of blender. When I reimport the FBX into a clean 2.9 project, the menu is back. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though it was opened in a later version of blender. When I reimport the FBX into a clean 2.9 project, the menu is back.